# how to get index from list when only part of string is contained in element?

Tags: java

Say I have a string

```
String s = bob
```

and the ArrayList

```
["alex [available]", "bob [away]", "craig [busy]", "david [gone fishing]"]
```

How would I search the list to get the element at [1]?

Comment: you want to get "bob" only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String strToSearch = yourString + " [";//"bob ["

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    if (list.get(i).startsWith(strToSearch)){
         neededIndex = i;
         break;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. But maybe add a `" ["` at the end of `yourstring` to not mix up Jon and Jonathan.

Answer (score 2):

You have to iterate the list and do a `String.contains("bob")` on every item.

```
for (String item : listOfItems) {
   if (item.contains("bob") {
      return item;
   }
}
```

Maybe you should extend the search term to `bob [` because "bob" might be contained in anoter name.

Comment: +1 for the enhanced for loop, and the return instead of ugly break, but OP probably wants a prefix match (did not say so, though).

Comment: `contains` is perhaps too broad. `"susan [bobbing for apples]"`

Answer (score 1):

You probably should be using a Map instead of a List. In this case you need to use a loop.

```
List<String> nameStatusList = ...
String s = "bob";

FOUND: {
    for(String ns: nameStatusList)
       if(ns.startsWith(s + " [")) {
           System.out.println(ns);
           break FOUND;
       }
    System.out.println("Couldn't find " + s);
}
```

Comment: @user714965 So it can handle the "not found" condition without additional checks.

Comment: Maybe an extra method and a `return ns`/`return null` is an idea.

Comment: @Thilo three people also suggested this ;) so I wanted to provide an alternative.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Re: alternative. You did mention using a better datastructure, too ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (String str: list) {
   if (str.contains(s)) {
      return str;
   }
}
```

Replace `str.contains(s)` with `str.matches("^"+s+" [")` just in case.

Comment: Regex injection vulnerability!

Comment: @Thilo You're right, we should avoid regex. But in this case isn't `str.matches("^"+s+" [")` equivalent to `str.startsWith(s+" [")`?

Comment: Not if `s = ".*"` for example. You need to escape/quote strings before putting them into a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
String string = "bob";

private List <String> list = new ArrayList<String>(){{
    add("alex [available]");
    add("bob [away]");
    add("craig [busy]");
    add("david [gone fishing]");
}};


public void method(){
    String answer;

    for (String s : list){
        if (s.contains(string)){
            answer = s;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```